# What is the best way to find only the non matching elements between two string arrays in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

What i have found so far is

```
select ARRAY(
   select unnest(ARRAY[ 'a', 'b', 'c' ])
   except
   select unnest(ARRAY[ 'c', 'd', 'e' ])
)
```

We can do this to  find only the non matching elements between two string  arrays.

Is there any other best way to do this ?

Like for integer array, We can do this

```
SELECT int[1,2,3] - int[2,3]
```

Comment: Your logic is wrong. Result should be (a,b,d,e) not only (a, b).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select array_agg(e order by e)
from (
    select e
    from
    (
        select unnest(array[ 'a', 'b', 'c' ])
        union all
        select unnest(array[ 'c', 'd', 'e' ])
    ) u (e)
    group by e
    having count(*) = 1
) s
```

Comment: I would suspect the original statement (from the question) to be more efficient.

Comment: This question is from the internet-Jurassic, but still... @ClodoaldoNeto 'wrong' is not the right way to put it. Your method gives the bidirectional difference (the elements that are unique to one or the other of the base arrays) but does not permit discrimination between them. The original statement gives the 'one way' difference - elements of array 1 that are not in array 2. I use that approach to detect things going into, and out of, arrays of addresses for multi-occupancy properties.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another alternative:

```
select ARRAY
(
   (
     select unnest(ARRAY[ 'c', 'd', 'e' ])
     except
     select unnest(ARRAY[ 'a', 'b', 'c' ])
   )
   union 
   (
     select unnest(ARRAY[ 'a', 'b', 'c' ])
     except
     select unnest(ARRAY[ 'c', 'd', 'e' ])
   )
);
```

Or (to make it more clear that two different arrays are involved):

```
with array_one (e) as (
   select unnest(ARRAY[ 'a', 'b', 'c' ])
), array_two (e) as (
   select unnest(ARRAY[ 'c', 'd', 'e' ])
)
select array(
   ( 
      select e from array_one
      except 
      select e from array_two
   )
   union 
   (
     select e from array_two
     except 
     select e from array_one
   )
) t;
```

If the order of elements is important, then array_agg() needs to be used as Clodoaldo Neto as done (instead of using the `array(...)` constructor):

```
with array_one (e) as (
   select unnest(ARRAY[ 'a', 'b', 'c' ])
), array_two (e) as (
   select unnest(ARRAY[ 'c', 'd', 'e' ])
)
select array_agg(e order by e)
from (
   ( 
      select e from array_one
      except 
      select e from array_two
   )
   union 
   (
     select e from array_two
     except 
     select e from array_one
   )
) t;
```